# What is the purpose of changing a function's context in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, web, this

For this block of code, I have change the context of "this" for the function to an object that is an instance of an array

```
function arrayContext(other_values){
    //...
    console.log(this);
    //... do something with other_values
}
arrayContext.call([1],some_other_values)
```

But what is the purpose of doing this? In what situation(s) can it be useful to change the context of a function?

Comment: When the function expects the value of `this` to be something specific. An example is jQuery event handlers. They create a specific callback, that mimics the native event handler, in which case `this` is set to the element that triggered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think out of `.call`, `.apply` and `.bind`, call is probably the least used - but all 3 methods are used to change the scope of a function.

In my opinion `.bind` is the most useful, since it returns a function with a forced scope, where `.call` and `.apply` will execute a function immediately.

Take the following contrived example, if you wanted to use certain methods as event handlers while maintaining scope of an object, then you'd use bind, otherwise the scope would change to the element we're binding an event to.

```
var singleton = {
  prop: 'howdy do!',

  method: function() {
    this.doSomething();
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
};

$('#thing').on('click',singleton.method.bind(singleton));
```

`.apply` is most commonly used to transform a single array into a collection of arguments.

```
var args = ['one', 2, false];

var singleton = {

  setStuff: function(place, index, isSomething) {
    this.place = place;
    this.index = index;
    this.isSomething = isSomething;
  }

};

singleton.setStuff.apply(singleton, args);
```

`.call` is commonly used to take advantage of certain prototyped methods where they wouldn't typically be available.

```
function myFunc() {
    // arguments isn't an array, so it doesn't have access to slice
    // however, by scoping the slice method to arguments, we can still use it
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

    singleton.setStuff.apply(singleton, args);
}
```